# Как писать блочные тесты (unit tests) для скриптов которые работают с базами данных?

Tags: mysql, веб-программирование, юнит-тесты

Какие существуют подходы для тестирования частей веб-приложения (скриптов), которые работают с базой данных изменяя ее содержимое, но которые не меняют структуру таблиц?

Answer (score 1):

#### Способ с непосредственным изменением данных в БД

Скрипт. Функция (метод) выполняют какие-либо *реальные* действия с данными в БД. Тестовый скрипт затем выполняет выборку проверяемых данных из БД, сверяет их с ожидаемыми и выводить результат проверки. После теста, изменённые данные возвращают в исходное состояние или удаляют.

#### Способ без взаимодействия с БД в принципе (mock-объекты)

Вместо драйвера (или любого механизма, который выполнят непосредственного взаимодействие с БД), используется его имитационный (mock) вариант, с преднастроенными результатами для конкретных SQL запросов. Например:

```
объектБД = инициироватьЛожноеПодключениеБД;

объектБД->добавитьЛожныйЗапрос(
   'SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ?', # для данного запроса
   [ ['Иван'] ]                           # выдать такой результат
);

функция получитьИмяПользователя (номерПользователя) {
    ...
    # объектБД - это "ложный" объект для работы с БД, который лишь
    #            делает вид, что взаимодействует с БД

    выборка = объектБД->выполнить(
        'SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ?', номерПользователя
    );
    ...
    возвратить выборка[0][0];
}

В тесте:

равно(получитьИмяПользователя(), "Иван", "имя пользователя Иван");
```

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от фреймворка:

- Порой ORM позволяет накрутить объекты «в памяти», без обращения к БД.
- Или можно использовать подменную SQLite-базу, также расположенную в памяти.

А вообще, коль скоро встаёт вопрос о блочных-тестах — блоки, отвечающие за работу с моделями, должны быть отделены от собственно базы данных (например, тем же ORM). Если же это не так и они не отделены — то это не блочное, а интеграционное тестирование.